# stop multi-threading in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

When using multi thread in python, and launching at the same time each thread will have to finish until it runs out

So, i want initiate multiple threads running in parallel
and when one of them is finished then stop all the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import threading
import time

class StopAll:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.run = True

    def run_and_end_in(self, seconds: int = None):
        i = 0
        while self.run:
            if seconds is not None:
                i += 1
                if i > seconds:
                    break
            time.sleep(1)
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.run = False
        self.lock.release()

    def test(self):
        th1 = threading.Thread(target=(self.run_and_end_in), args=(10,))
        th2 = threading.Thread(target=(self.run_and_end_in), args=(None,))
        start = time.time()
        th1.start()
        th2.start()
        th1.join()
        th2.join()
        print(time.time() - start)


StopAll().test()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a flag which will be updated when a thread has stopped to stop the other threads from executing.

```
import threading
import time

finished_flag = False


def thread_function(thread_id):
    global finished_flag
    print(f"Thread {thread_id} started.")
    while not finished_flag:
        print(f"Thread {thread_id} is running...")
        time.sleep(1)

    print(f"Thread {thread_id} stopped.")


threads = []
for i in range(5):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(i,))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()
    finished_flag = True

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```